# Change values of datatable column conditionally using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, .net-3.5

I have a data table with one column having 0/1 values. I need to change all the 1's to 'Yes' and all the 0's to 'No', using Linq (C#).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ is Language-Integrated **Query**. It's purpose is querying data, not changing data. So, for this task you should use simple loop:

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
   string value = row.Field<string>("foo") == "0" ? "No" : "Yes";
   row.SetField("foo", value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use linq projection:

```
var results = from p in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              select new{ yesno = p.Field<int>("yesno") == 1 ? "Yes" : "No", otherField = p.Field<string>("otherField")};
```

Answer (score -2):

What do you mean by "data table" ?
ADO .net DataTable object or actual table in database ?

If it means actual table in database then what are you using to load it, like Entity Framework or Linq to SQL or stored procudures ?

Comment: Clarification questions should be posted in the comments of the OP question.